# How to read file from createReadStream in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, fs

I have web appication that can upload excel file. If user upload, the app should parse it and will return some rows that file have. So, **The application don't need to save file to its filesystem. Parsing file and return rows is a job.** But below code, I wrote this morning, it save file to its server and then parse it.. I think it's waste server resource.

I don't know how to read excel file with `createReadStream`. Without saving file, how can I parse excel directly? I am not familiar with `fs`, of course, I can delete file after the job finished, but is there any elegant way?

```
import { createWriteStream } from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import xlsx from 'node-xlsx'

// some graphql code here... 


async singleUpload(_, { file }, context) {
    try {
    console.log(file)
    const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file

    await new Promise((res) =>
        createReadStream()
        .pipe(createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, '../uploads', filename)))
        .on('close', res)
    )

    const workSheetsFromFile = xlsx.parse(path.join(__dirname, '../uploads', filename))
    for (const row of workSheetsFromFile[0].data) {
        console.log(row)
    }

    return { filename }
    } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e)
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `express-fileupload` library which provides a buffer representation for uploaded files (through `data` property), combined with `excel.js` which accepts a buffers will get you there.

see [Express-fileupload](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload#readme) and [Excel.js](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs)

```
// read from a file
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
await workbook.xlsx.readFile(filename);
// ... use workbook


// read from a stream
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
await workbook.xlsx.read(stream);
// ... use workbook


// load from buffer  // this is what you're looking for
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
await workbook.xlsx.load(data);
// ... use workbook
```

Here's a simplified example:

```
const app = require('express')();
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const { Workbook } = require('exceljs');

app.use(fileUpload());

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
        return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
    }
     // The name of the input field (i.e. "myFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
    await new Workbook().xlsx.load(req.files.myFile.data)
});

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xlsx = require('xlsx')

//var workbook = xlsx.readFile('testSingle.xlsx')
var workbook = xlsx.read(fileObj);
```

You just need to use xlsx.read method to read a stream of data.

Answer (score 0):

you can add an event listener before you pipe the data, so you can do something with your file before it uploaded, it look like this

```
async singleUpload(_, { file }, context) {
    try {
    console.log(file)
    const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file

    await new Promise((res) =>
        createReadStream()
        .on('data', (data)=>{
         //do something with your data/file
        console.log({data})
        //your code here
        })
        .pipe(createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, '../uploads', filename)))
        .on('close', res)
    )
 
},
```

you can see the documentation
[stream node js](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_new_stream_readable_options)